# Console logs disappear quickly

Tags: usb-debugging, logging

When I debug any app (native or hybrid), the console device logs they appear in the **logcat** but after **2+** min they automatically **cleared out** by Eclipse - though my device does not go in sleep mode.

It becomes difficult for me to check the logs and every time I have to first copy the logs to a text editor and then checking the logs.

Is there any settings required in eclipse or device?

Comment: Since this is a programming-related question, it would be much more suitable to ask this on Stackoverflow instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's cleared because the log has exceeded the maximum limit of displayed messages on LogCat. You can change the limit by following [the answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429931/2821954):

> The LogCat messages were simple getting cleared because the buffer had run out of space (receiving too many new messages), which is a simple setting change in Eclipse.
>
> To fix, go to Window > Preferences > Android > LogCat
>
> and increase the limit for "Maximum number of LogCat messages to buffer". Set it to 0 for unlimited size, or a really big number. But keep in mind, anything below 10000 fills up real fast.